# Joomla: How to show a different image on every page

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I'm new to Joomla, but I figured out how to set it up and create my first joomla template which only includes the content area and a top menu.

Now I want to display a different images on every page.
I do not know how to do it in Joomla, because as far as I know I can only write articles (with images in them, which is not what I want) and include them in the Menu Items as Layout: Article.

Can I somehow create my own parameters for the Layout: Article and use them in my template? The cms user should be able to decide which image to show on each "page".

Comment: I have a right hand module for several pages to add photos. However I get the same photo on each page. How do I get different photos on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by means of a module. You can define for which menu position each module is visible. You can put any article inside a module with a [Article as Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/content-embed/7528) extension

Comment: "You can define for which menu position each module is visible" how do I do that?

Comment: Log in to the backend and go to Extensions->Module Manager. Choose a module you want and edit its properties. When in edit view you have a "Menu Assignment" box on the bottom left. You can show this module for all menu postions, for none of them or selected ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lots of modules at http://extensions.joomla.org/ which you can install from your administrator and enable it on a position to show different images on different pages. 
check this page
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-rotators

Answer (score 0):

Header Image

https://support.pillwax.com/open-source/doku.php?id=joomla:header_image

This allows you to place your images in a folder and name them according to the page. You can match to articleid, menuid, category, section, or even show a rotating random image.

You would then just need to publish the module in the correct position.